# Meteor won't allow a second client connection with dedicated Mongo server

Tags: meteor

I cannot seem to connect to my Meteor server more than once after it initially starts up.  The problem appears to be related to the dedicated Mongo server that I installed locally or the size of the collection.

If I `$ export MONGO_URL=`, Meteor uses its built-in MongoDB implementation without data and everything works perfectly.

When I `$ export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost...`, then start Meteor `$ meteor` the app works perfectly for the very first client request.  It is fast to load and populates the total count of items in the database (~250,000).  If I request the page again from another tab, or simply refresh the page the browser will never finish loading.

I have not seen any change from calling `$ export DISABLE_WEBSOCKETS=true` prior to the launch of Meteor.

```
// email-tracker.js
// Note: The `Counts` object comes from `tmeasday:publish-counts`.
//       This is all of the JavaScript code in my app.

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.subscribe('emailPublication');

  Template.body.helpers({
    totalEmails: function() {
      return Counts.get('totalEmails');
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish('emailPublication', function() {
    Counts.publish(this, 'totalEmails', Emails.find());
  });
}

Emails = new Mongo.Collection("emails");
```

The Mongo DB Collection it is working with is pretty small (125MiB).  The server remains very responsive on the command line, even when new browser clients cannot connect to Meteor properly.

```
> db.emails.stats(1048576);
{
    "ns" : "emailTracker.emails",
    "count" : 264694,
    "size" : 125,
    "avgObjSize" : 495,
    "storageSize" : 1111,
    "numExtents" : 18,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 293,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 1,
    "userFlags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 16,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 16
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

The `.meteor/packages` file:

```
meteor-platform
nooitaf:semantic-ui
meteorhacks:npm


npm-container
meteorhacks:async
tmeasday:publish-counts
```

Comment: what happens when you connect to your mongodb using the mongo shell and make the same request (`db.emails.find()`)? Is that slow, too? how did you start your mongodb server. is it the default configuration on ubuntu?

Comment: The mongo shell responds instantly.  Mongo is using the default configuration on xubuntu.  The odd thing is that Meteor hits the Mongo DB and responds instantly as well... but only once.